# How do i import a new branch from github using git?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-clone

how do i import a new branch from github using git? I tried `git clone https:blablabla.com/blabla.git`, but it did give me an error like this: `fatal: destination path 'FolderName' already exists and is not an empty directory.` Can anyone help, please?

Comment: `git clone` doesn't "import" (well, fetch) a branch — it clones (copies locally) the entire remote repository. Do you have a local repository already and want to fetch another branch? Or do you want to clone to a new empty directory?

Comment: Yes, I do have a local repo with the main branch, but not with the one I want to code on. @phd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+branch

Comment: `git fetch origin && git checkout new_branch_name`